# Android Sqlite getReadableDatabase

Tags: android, sqlite

Can any body help me please. I'm doing timetable application, so working with database.

My program crashes here:

```
DatabaseHandler dbHelper = new DatabaseHandler(this.getApplicationContext());

                SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase(); //<---------------

                Cursor cur=null;
                 cur = dbHelper.fetchAll(db, "SELECT * FROM timetable");

                db.close();
```

My DatabaseHandler class is here:

```
public DatabaseHandler (Context context) {

    super(context,DATABASE_NAME, null,DATABASE_VERSION);

}

//Creating Table
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){

    String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_NAME + "("
            + KEY_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_SUBJECT_NAME
            + "TEXT," + KEY_SUBJECT_CODE + "TEXT," + KEY_SUBJECT_VENUE
            + "TEXT," + KEY_TIME + "INTEGER," + KEY_DAY + "INTEGER" + ")";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}

//Upgrading Database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){

    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);

}

 /**
 * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
 */

//Insert data
public void insertValues(int day, int time, String name, String code, String venue) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_DAY, day);
    values.put(KEY_TIME, time);
    values.put(KEY_SUBJECT_NAME, name);
    values.put(KEY_SUBJECT_CODE, code);
    values.put(KEY_SUBJECT_VENUE, venue);

    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);

    //closing the database connection
    db.close();
}

public Cursor fetchAll(SQLiteDatabase db, String query){

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
      db.close();
    return cursor;

}
```

}

I would be more than happy If someone could help me, cause this is my Final Year Project :)

Comment: I just need to fetch all the data in databse

Comment: this is very simple just compare your code: http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2011/11/sqlite-database-with-cursor-adapter-in.html & http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html &  http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2012/10/android-show-data-from-sqlite-db-into.html  ,there is so many tutorials on net.

Comment: It would be helpful to *not* keep the error message a secret.

Comment: The answer was found!

The main problem was with Query in onCreate Method, no white spaces between entries, so stupid :)

Answer (score 4):

Most likely your `Context` is null. Try to use just `this` instead of `getApplicationContext()`

```
dbHelper = new DatabaseHandler(this);
```

**Note:** I recommend to do it rather like this:

```
public Cursor fetchAll(SQLiteDatabase db, String query) {
    Cursor cursor;
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    if (db != null) {
       cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null); // also rather use query method, ist more saf
    }
    return cursor;
}
```

If you have method that returns `Cursor`, you shouldn't call `db.close()`. If you call it, your `Cursor` in `Activity` will thrown error that "is empty".

To release `Cursors` etc, i recommend to use `onPause()` or `onDestroy()` methods of `Activity` but also it depends on `Context` of method.

So if your method is used for adding, updating or removing data from database so then in your method i recommend to you use `try-finally` block or `try-catch-finally` and now you should call `db.close()` to have you solution clean without spaghetti code.

So little example:

```
public boolean addRecord(String name, String pass, String value) {
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    try {
       db = this.getWritableDatabase();
       ContentValues data = new ContentValues();
       data.put(KEY_NAME, name);
       data.put(KEY_PASS, pass);
       data.put(KEY_VALUE, value);
       long result = db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_NAME, <nullColumnHack>, data);
       return result > 0;
    catch (SQLException ex) {
       Log.w("SQLException", ex.fillInStackTrace());
       return false;
    }
    finally {
       if (db != null) {
          db.close();
       }
    }
}
```

Methods where you work with **cursors**, **database** and they return for example `String`, `List<T>` or other data-type so also here you should call `close()` method on **cursors** and **database** to have clean solution.

But how i meant about method that returns fetched data from **database**, do not call `close()` method on **db**.

Hope it helps colleague.

Comment: Sorry, but why finally block doesn't see db variable in your example, i mean it asks to create local variable outside try block

Comment: sorry, i already fixed it. yes you need to declare variable outside of try.

Comment: The answer was found!

The main problem was with Query in onCreate Method, no white spaces between entries, so stupid :)